# MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited setting in Elasticsearch 8.x

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-8

Is `MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited` settings in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` (on Ubuntu) still necessary in **Elasticsearch 8.x**?

It looks like settings in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` system configuration file is quite simplified and the commented **MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY** setting is not present like in previous Elasticsearch versions.

I still use `bootstrap.memory_lock: true` in `elasticsearch.yml`.

I asked in Elasticsearch [Discuss](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/max-locked-memory-unlimited-setting-in-elasticsearch-8-x/329884), but without success. I also tried to find this in the
Elasticsearch documentation, but found nothing.